# Connection created for CDS in PowerApp platform not appearing in dropdown list for making ConnectionSet in PowerApp Admin portal

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps

I have created a CDS connection in PowerApp platform under particular environment which I can see in list there as follows:

[image]

But when I go to PowerApp admin portal and try to use these connection to create a ConnectionSet then only single connection appears there, which is of Dynamics 365 for Operation. I don't see any other connection to choose from to proceed with integration task. My intention is to integrate the CDS data from associated Dynamics 365 for Talent to Dynamics 365 for Operation.

Screenshot of ConnectionSet creation step with only available connection:
[image]

Please let me know what I have missing and hence the other connection not appearing in list.

Answer (score 2):

To tell if a connection can be used by Data Integration, please try the instructions below.

1. Log on to https://admin.powerapps.com/environments using Chrome
2. Enable network trace (F12) for the browser, and switch to [Network] tab
3. Type [integratorApp] in the filter editor box
   [Power Apps Admin Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qJtv.png)
4. Click [Data integration] to switch to Data Integration page
5. In the network trace tab, look for [targetTypes] and in the [Preview] tab, observe a list of supported types and their corresponding apiId’s.
6. For [Common data service], the type is [CDS2] and apiId [/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_commondataservice]

[Supported Target types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxUM1.png)

7. In the [Network] tab, type [powerApps] in the filter edit box
8. Click on [+New connection set] to open [Connection Set] dialog
9. In the [Network] tab, look for [connections?api-version…]. There might be more than one calls if you have multiple PowerApps environment.
10. Switch to [Preview] in the response, observer connections that have apiID’s matching what are supported, and check if the connection in question is listed.

[Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G536U.png)

Comment: Thanks Chunke for the detailed steps to debug the issue. In meantime I had a call with MS person and they pointed out that the environment I m using is not upgraded to CDS 2.0 and still its on CDS 1.0. CDS 1.0 don't support data integration. Hence connection made for CDS1.0 never appears in connection list to form the Connection set.